# Visual Studio becomes unresponsive on compile attempt

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I attempt to compile a project(clicking Local Windows Debugger) Visual Studio becomes completely unresponsive

This only happens with new projects, all my previous projects compile and run properly, in fact, I am able to open a new instance of VS with a working project and run it while the other one is failing to compile.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times.

I did a little test where I attempted to run an empty project with one .cpp source file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

I got an "entry point needs to be defined" error, which is expected.

but once I add

```
int main(){return 0};
```

It will just become unresponsive when I click the debug button. Again, while I futilely wait to see if it compiles, I am able to open another instance of VS with a previous project that works.

Comment: Do you use Avast antivirus?

Comment: Ah, I completely overlooked antivirus problems because of the old projects still working. I disabled the file protection and the new projects work now. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like it, though in my case no command line, nothing, just an unresponsive VS.

Comment: Yeah, I've been collecting duplicates of this Avast issue and a frozen IDE is another common symptom.